# ClickOnce error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: .net, apache, clickonce, socketexception

I have an annoying problem. I have application deployed by clickonce. Until now it was working really well and a lot of updates were deployed easilly. This time I had to do some major changes in my app. That causes update is about 16MB. Unfortunately most of time on clients computers error occurs during downloading update (in random moment):

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Menu Start\Programy\Marketell\Marketell.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading http://xx.xx.xx.xx/Marketell 2/Application Files/Marketell_1_0_1_2/CounterPathSDK.dll.deploy did not succeed.
    + Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    + An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

And some details:

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [2011-11-28 14:02:34] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading http://xx.xx.xx.xx/Marketell 2/Application Files/Marketell_1_0_1_2/CounterPathSDK.dll.deploy did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ConsumeUpdatedDeployment(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentUpdate(SubscriptionState& subState, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.IO.IOException
    - Unable to read data from the transport connection: Istniejące połączenie zostało gwałtownie zamknięte przez zdalnego hosta.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
    - Istniejące połączenie zostało gwałtownie zamknięte przez zdalnego hosta
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
        at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Ofcourse I replaced real IP by Xs.
Only once it updated properly. I use WAMP as the HTTP server. 
I've been Googling it for some time, but haven't found anything usefull acutally.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but I had this issue today and it turned out to be the client's firewall blocking the download of binaries from the ClickOnce server. We added an exception and it worked fine.

Comment: I totally forgot about this question I admit. What you wrote could be the cause but that's not the case this time. I've found the Apache was closing those connections if there were a lot of new connections. Still haven't found out why.